# how to remove white space in circle UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I wanted to circle my UIImageView and added this code :

```
profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = profileImage.frame.size.height/2
    profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
```

and it work perfectly, but when images are horizontal, I get this picture:
[image]

as you can see, there is white space at the bottom and top of my circle image view. but what I really wanted was a circle filled with my image!
I've tried changing "content Mode" from attribute inspector, but I didn't get any answer! how can I fix this issue?

Comment: use profileImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill

Comment: As explained in the [`UIImageView` Docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) change the `contentMode`

Comment: Just set image rendering mode to scaleAspectFill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have already set the `clipsToBound` property. So just update the `contentMode`.

**I you don't want to distort image's scale:**

```
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

**If image's scale does not matter, you also can use:**

```
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleToFill
```

> Follow the link for more details: https://useyourloaf.com/blog/stretching-redrawing-and-positioning-with-contentmode/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Set the `contentMode` of your UIImageView to `scaleAspectFill`

```
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Keep in mind that using this contentMode option some portion of the content may be clipped to fill the view’s bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Use below code:-

```
profileImage.clipsToBounds = true
profileImage.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Different Content Mode as per you choice from StoryBoard:

[image]

You can select

1. Scale to Fill
2. Aspect Fill

or any other content mode by using trial and Error method which suits you

Hope it Helps.

Answer (score 1):

If I choose `Aspect Fit`, I'm getting blank space in top and bottom of the imageview.

Can I trim that space anyhow?

Is there any programatically constraints I can set to re-scale imageview according to actual image size?